# Java Input & Output Array

Tags: java

Working on a java program that reads a txt file with a bunch of account numbers. User enters account number if it matches the programs responds saying its a valid account number if its not it responds invalid. Here is my class that opens the file and checks to see if it is a valid number. When I run the code it always comes back saying the account number is invalid even though the account number I am testing is valid.

```
public class Validator {

    public boolean isValid(int number) throws IOException {


        final int SIZE = 17;
        int[] numbers = new int[SIZE];
        boolean found = false;
        int index = 0;


        File file = new File("src/Accounts.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        while (inputFile.hasNext() && index < numbers.length) {

            numbers[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
            index++;

        }

        while (!found && index < SIZE) {

            if (numbers[index] == (number))
                found = true;
            else
                index++;
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: What numbers are in your txt-File? Are they of fixed lenght?

Comment: How is your `Accounts.txt` looks like?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I'd suggest you avoid reading in the file every single time you validate a number. Store the contents in-memory, use those stored values, maybe provide some sort of `reset()` method that reloads the file.

Comment: Would I load it into an array list?

Comment: @Nik I noticed below you said you have to use an array, I just wanted to point out that an `ArrayList` is not an array. An `ArrayList` *uses* arrays but I wouldn't consider it okay if you've been told you have to use an array. I'd have to see the rules to be sure though.

Comment: I would assume I could use an ArrayList only because it was shown in the Array chapter. It's basically a programming challenge at the end of the chapter so in this case a Arraylist would be okay to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should reset index back to 0 before your second loop. Otherwise, the second loop won't be entered, since the first loop already incremented `index` past the index of the last account number read from the file.

```
while (inputFile.hasNext() && index < numbers.length) {

    numbers[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
    index++;

}

index = 0; // add this

while (!found && index < SIZE) {

    if (numbers[index] == (number))
        found = true;
    else
        index++;
}
return found;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your code a bit. You can go through the file and check at the same time.

```
public boolean isValid(int number) {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("src/Accounts.txt"))) {
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            if (scanner.nextInt() == number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have to use an array for this problem. It's one of the requirements for the programming challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your code too, but I found a possible problem in your parameter type for account numbers.
Can your account bigger than "2,147,483,647"?
(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_datatypes.htm)

If the answer is yes, so you will have a problem.

The simplified code is below:

```
public boolean isValid(long number) {
    long accountNumber;

    File file = new File("src/Accounts.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = null;
    try {
        inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            accountNumber = inputFile.nextLong();
            if (accountNumber == number) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputFile != null) {
            inputFile.close();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you solved your problem, you can try another elegant way using java 8:

```
public boolean isValid(int number) throws IOException{

        return Files.lines(Paths.get("src/Accounts.txt")).anyMatch(
                    num -> num.trim().equals(String.valueOf(number)));

}
```